# Getting email from user in Firebase Microsoft Account Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the following code to authenticate a Firebase user who signs in with a Microsoft account:

```
  signInMicrosoft = () => {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
    provider.addScope('openid');
    provider.addScope('email');
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(
        function(result) {
          console.log('result', result)
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
          var user = result.user;
          var isNewUser = result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
          //window.location.href = "/";
        }.bind(this)
      )
      .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        this.setState({
          loginError: true
        });
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
    });
  }
```

However, when I try to access the user's email with the following code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  console.log('user', user) 
});
```

The 'user.email' entry is set to null. How do I enable Firebase to access the Microsoft account's email in this fashion, so that 'user.email' is set to the user's email?

Comment: You may need to include the `User.Read` scope before this will start showing up.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur just tried that, it did not work.

Comment: Are you using the "multiple accounts per email" setting in the Firebase Console?

Comment: @bojeil, yes I am.

Comment: Yeah then this is expected. In that case the top level email is null and the email is populated in the `firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].email`.

Comment: Is there a way to populate the user.email entry, or to update it somehow upon connecting the Microsoft account @bojeil?

Comment: You can always call `user.updateEmail(user.providerData[0].email)` or switch to one account per email setting.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a shot then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I tried.

I could get email address.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-individual-user-consent

> At this time, the offline_access ("Maintain access to data you have given it access to") and user.read ("Sign you in and read your profile") permissions are automatically included in the initial consent to an application. These permissions are generally required for proper app functionality - offline_access gives the app access to refresh tokens, critical for native and web apps, while user.read gives access to the sub claim, allowing the client or app to correctly identify the user over time and access rudimentary user information

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#openid-permissions

> **Important** The Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) currently specifies offline_access, openid, profile, and email by default in authorization and token requests. This means that, for the default case, if you specify these permissions explicitly, Azure AD may return an error.

`provider.addScope();` is not necessary.

Please try comment out or delete `provider.addScope();`

```
    // provider.addScope('openid');
    // provider.addScope('email');
```

And you should check your Microsoft applications settings.

Microsoft Graph Permissions > Delegated Permissions set User.Read.?

Remarks:

`provider.addScope('mail.read');` in the following documentation allows the app to read email in user mailboxes.
Not allows the app to read user email address.

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#mail-permissions

Comment: Yeah, just tried that. Still can't get the email :(.

Comment: I was wrong. `provider.addScope('mail.read');`  allows the app to read email in user mailboxes. Not allows the app to read user email address. I edited my answer. I tried.
I could get email address.

Comment: are you saying that after authenticating the user using microsoft, you could get their email addressing by calling user.email on the Firebase user object?

Comment: @Alex, yes I am. Code is here. https://github.com/zkohi/firebase-web-samples/tree/microsoft-oauth. If you does not work then you may needs try to create  
 new Microsoft account and new Microsoft application.